# Remove new line from batch prompt

Tags: prompt

I have the following prompt:

```
PS1="\[\033[s\033[0;0H\033[0;41m\033[K\033[1;33mCWD:\w | \d | \t | CM: \# | \V\s\033[0m\033[u\]
<\[\033[0;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[0m\]>\$"
```

Everytime I type a command, it types a new line after. How can I remove it?

The output is:

```
prompt->ls
a.c b.c d.c

prompt->
```

And I want it to be

```
prompt->ls
a.c b.c d.c
prompt->
```

Can this be done, while keeping the initial text on the top.

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/355310). You have received two almost identical answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you place the entire variable on one line then it does not add a new line after the prompt.

Tested and working on GNU bash, version 4.4.19 for RHEL 8.3

```
PS1="\[\033[s\033[0;0H\033[0;41m\033[K\033[1;33mCWD:\w | \d | \t | CM: \# | \V\s\033[0m\033[u\]<\[\033[0;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[0m\]>\$ "


<user@hostname>$ls
a.txt  b.txt
<user@hostname>$
```

Comment: You could also escape the literal newline.

Comment: If I do that, the text on the top stays in front of the prompt

Comment: @DuarteArribas Which OS and shell are you using?

Comment: Windows with wsl. The shell is batch